# Remote ssh twice

Tags: ssh

I am trying to execute commands over ssh remotely.
It's 2x remote (2 level deep).
From my host, I ssh into target1 which is connected to target2.
I need the commands executed on target2.
There is no direct connection from host to target2.
Ex:
ssh root@target1 -t "ssh root@target2 -t "cat /usr/value""
The above command works.
ssh root@target1 -t "ssh root@target2 -t "echo 1 > /usr/value""
This command does not work. I get "No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a shell feature (redirection) instead of a command, so run that via shell (note: quoting gets tricky):

```
ssh -t root@target1 'ssh -t root@target2 /bin/bash -c \"echo 1 > /usr/value\"'
```

I suggest you study the man page for ssh_config.  For instance, with this:

```
Host target2
   User root
   ProxyJump root@target1
```

your above command would be:

```
ssh -t target2 '/bin/bash -c "echo 1 > /usr/value"'
```

The next step is to use ansible (or similar) for system changes.